# Where is the defining JAR of the portlet taglibs in IBM Websphere Portal 7?

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I'm trying to build portlets for websphere in Eclipse Juno. Everything works so far, building and running the WAR files on WPS7 is ok.

But in my JSP editor I get a lot of warnings:

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/WEB-INF/tld/portal.tld"
```

In my JSP file I'm using the usual taglib line:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet"%>
```

Now I wonder if I have to bring the actual JAR file that defines this tag into my eclipse or if there is something else that I missed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a Portal 8 installation but the structure should be similar.

I found a jar containing portal.tld at [Portal Install root]\Portal Server\base\wp.engine.tags\shared\app\wp.engine.tags.jar

Though as a more complete solution you might want to include the whole base folder into your classpath. The server runtime RAD adds to my portlet project include lots of jars from that folder as part of the basic setup. It also includes many jars from [WAS Install root]\App Server\plugins. Since you're just using Eclipse instead of RAD (which would help manage the Portal server jars) you'll probably want to create a user library to manage all these jars.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this error message has nothing to do with the `taglib` declaration you had quoted. The latter refers to the standard Portlet tag library (JSR-168), whereas the former has to do with WebSphere Portal's proprietary tags, needed to use WebSphere Portal-specific facilities.

I am guessing that `portal.tld` is referred-to by your `web.xml`.

When developing portlets under RAD, IBM's RAD plugins ensure that this TLD file is known to the JSP compiler, by virtue of attaching the WebSphere Portal runtime - in its entirety - to the Dynamic Web Project's classpath.

Under Eclipse Juno, this isn't done for you. You will have to find the JAR file that contains it (which might vary from one WebSphere Portal release to another) and add it to your compile-time classpath.

Having said that, you may want to consider why you need that `web.xml` declaration in the first place. With Portal 7.0, most of IBM's tag libraries can be referred to by their URI's, rather than having to specifically mention the TLD file.

Answer (score 1):

In RAD/Eclipse, assuming you have the Portal 8 Stubs and Developer Tools installed, you can go to Project->Project Properties -> Java Build Path, to the Libraries tab, Go to Add Library -> Server Runtime , and you should see "Websphere Portal 8" or whichever version you have installed ... once that library is added your URI problems should be resolved.This essentially adds every jar file in the entire portal installation to the build path. If you do not have the stubs and development tools installed, or if you are using another IDE, you will need to add the jar files manually to the build path ....